# How to give camera permission for phonegap hybrid app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I want to give permission for camera into my phonegap hybrid app.But i am confused where to place the permission and the right way to write the permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Cordova camera plugin to your app. You can first install it by,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Please refer the [official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html) for all the information on this.